# Right way of adding External Libraries to Maven based JSF project

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working on a project based on Maven + JSF + PrimeFaces and I can run it and there is no problem. But I have some questions.

I added PrimeFaces dependency in `pom.xml` and after updating Maven, `Maven:org.primefaces:primefaces:5.2` file was added to the "External Libraries" section. At this time, I can use PrimeFaces namespaces etc, but I can't use its components like `Editor` until I added `primefaces-5.2.jar` file to the `lib` folder. and then code works and PrimeFaces components loads to the page.

What is the difference between this two imports that I've done?

I was thinking that if I add PrimeFaces dependency in `pom.xml` and load it, everything works fine but it does not! Right now, if I remove PrimeFaces dependency from `pom.xml`, all code related to PrimeFaces turn to red in IDE and looks something missed, but because I have PrimeFaces jar file in lib folder, the code still works! I don't get it.

Comment: What is the difference between what and what? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Tunaki: i added Primefaces library i two places. in pom.xml that adds a file to external libraries section and put a jar file on lib folder. are these two part essential? when i say difference, i mean these two imports that i done. as i say, i i remove Primefaces dependency from pom.xml code works but Primefaces codes in IDE turn to red. Why? i have to do both of them?

Comment: Whats in the pom? Did you add the primefaces repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mixing up two separate concerns so I will try to explain it simply.

When you are adding a dependency to your application (through the POM), this dependency gets added to the classpath of this application. The classpath represents every dependencies that are needed to *compile* the application. This means, after adding it, you will be able to use and import the classes inside that dependency and the code will compile. Without the dependency in the classpath, the compiler would have no way to resolve the imports, hence the errors you get when you remove it from the POM. Every IDE has its own way of presenting the classpath in a nice format to the user. For IntelliJ, which you are using, the classpath is presented with the "External Libraries" list. As such, "External Libraries" is only IntelliJ's way of showing to you what the classpath is and what it contains.

Everything up until now has been at "compile-time". The result of the web application is a `war` file that needs to be deployed on a web server. We are now getting into what's called "run-time". A `war` is a file containing all of the code of the web application, including all of its dependencies. They need to be present in the `war` so that the web server can correctly load the classes and resolve the imports. Those dependencies are always located in the folder `WEB-INF/lib` (that's just how it is). As such, a library that is in this folder represents a dependency that is needed at runtime, i.e. it is needed for the application to *run*.

That's why you have both of them (but it is in fact the same dependency): one represents the dependency needed at compile-time and the other represents the dependency needed at run-time.

When creating a `war` file, Maven will automatically position all of your classpath dependencies (except for the provided ones) into `WEB-INF/lib` so that they are correctly resolved at run-time.

Comment: But why does'nt Maven put the jar in the war automatically?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar It does add automatically the jar inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the war.

Comment: So, in a Maven project add dependencies **only** through the pom file. However, in non Maven projects, or non Gradle projects, you will need add them through your IDE via External Libraries in IntelliJ's, via Project Properties > Java Build Path in Eclipse, etc.

Comment: @Tunaki It seems to me to be the problem that it did'nt do it automatically, but maybe thats just me